# XML PAYLOAD input with WebResource PUT

Tags: java, xml, jersey, webresource

I have a xml payload which I am input to a webresource PUT .
I am getting a error 400 bad request
my payload:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<value>100</value>
<name>a</name>
```

code :

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("url");
String input ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><value>100</value><name>a</name>";
ClientResponse res=webResource.webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).header("Content-Type","application-xml").put(ClientResponse.class,input);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid XML. XML can only have a single root element. You have two, `value` and `name`. If you wrap it in a root element, then it would be valid

```
<data>
    <value>100</value>
    <name>a</name>
</data>
```

What exactly the root element name should be, I don't know. It's up to the server.

Comment: But I am passing the XML as a string

Comment: And how is it handled on the server? It's the server that is sending the bad request, the client. The server is sending a Bad request probably because it's not valid XML